# When and what time does the Navratri fast end?

Tags: fasting, navrathri

Could anyone can tell me when and at what time does the Navratri fast end?

And how to calculate it?

Comment: Also can someone explain what the navaratri fast is? Is it a fast for all nine days?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Navaratri basically represents a celebration of the Goddess Durga,
>   with nava meaning nine and ratri meaning nights Navratri is “Nine
>   Nights festival”.
>
> The commencement of spring and autumn are considered to be an
>   important junction of atmospheric and solar influences, and this is
>   the reason why these two periods are taken as sacred prospects for the
>   worship of the Divine Durga Maa. The dates of the festival are
>   determined according to the astrophysical calendar. Goddess Durga has
>   nine Avatars and all these nine avatars are worshiped in this nine
>   days festival, called Navratri.
>
> Navratri is a very important and major festival in the western states
>   like Gujarat, Maharashtra, and Karnataka, during this festival the
>   traditional dance of Gujarat called “Garba” is performed with full
>   zeal and enjoyment. The festival has a great value in North India as
>   well, including Bihar, West Bengal, Madhya Pradesh and the northern
>   state of Punjab.
>
> **food allowed for navratri vrat or fast**
>
> - Singhare ka atta (water chestnut flour)
> - Kuttu ka atta (buckwheat flour)
> - Rajgira ka atta (amaranth flour) and rajgira (amaranth)
> - Sama ke chawal ka atta (barnyard millet flour)
> - Vrat ke chawal (barnyard millet)
> - Arrowroot flour or paniphal flour
>
> **Spices & herbs allowed for navratri fasting**
>
> - Cumin or cumin powder ( jeera or jeera powder )
> - Black pepper powder and rock salt (sendha namak)
> - Green cardamom (chhoti illaichi), cloves (laung), black peppercorns (saboot kali mirch), cinnamon (dalchini) and nutmeg (jaiphal)
> - Dry pomegranate seeds (anardana) – you can make chutney or raita or use it as a souring agent.
> - Ginger – both fresh as well as dry, including dry ginger powder
> - Green chilli or hari mirch and lemons.
> - Ajwain or carom seeds
>
> **Navratri 2016 Dates**
>
> Day 1 - October 1, 2016 (Saturday) - Pratipada, Ghatsthapana,
>   Shailputri Puja
>
> Day 2 - October 2, 2016 (Sunday) - Pratipada, Chandra Darshan,
>   Shailputri Puja
>
> Day 3 (Dwitiya) - October 3, 2016 (Monday) - Brahmacharini Puja
>
> Day 4 (Tritiya) - October 4, 2016 (Tuesday) - Chandraghanta Puja
>
> Day 5 (Chaturthi) - October 5, 2016 (Wednesday) - Kushmanda puja
>
> Day 6 (Panchami) - October 6, 2016 (Thursday) - Skandamata Puja
>
> Day 7 (Shashthi) - October 7, 2016 (Friday) - Katyayani Puja
>
> Day 8 (Saptami) - October 8, 2016 (Saturday) - Kalaratri Puja
>
> Day 9 (Mahashtmi) - October 9, 2016 (Sunday) - Mahagauri Puja, Durga
>   Maha Ashtami Puja, Saraswati Puja
>
> Day 10 (Navami) - October 10, 2016 (Monday) - Siddhidatri Pooja, Maha
>   Navami, Ayudha Puja, Navami Homa
>
> Day 11 (Dashami or Dussehra) - October 11, 2016 (Tuesday) - Navratri
>   Parana, Durga Visarjan, Vijyadashmi (Dussehra)

**When navratri fast Ends or Completes**

Some people do kanjak pooja on 8th day (ashtami) and some do it on 9th day (navami) and few people do it on dussehra (10th). mostly it is done on 8th or 9th day. The day kanjak pooja is done, on that day we do the immersion of khetri along with red cloth (chunri) in moving water or it can be kept under pippal tree in a temple.

Normally, Pooja is completed early morning itself. if you also want to do kanjak pooja on 9th then keep fast on 8th (ashtami) as many people keep fast on 1st and last day of navratri.

[image]

Reference http://www.pandit.com/recent-articles/

[Source](http://www.vegrecipesofindia.com/navratri-fasting-rules-vrat-ka-khana/)

Comment: Good explanation, but OP wants to know when the fast ends. Like some people do fast till `Navami`, some till `Ashtami` and even some till `Saptami`. But what are the day to break fast (Parana) as suggested by scriptures or Acharyas?

Comment: @Triyugi Narayan Mani : I have edit the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Ashtami or the eighth day of Navratri marks the end of fasting for several devotees. They offer prayers to Mahagauri and perform the Kanchika Pujan, where young girls who are considered a manifestation of the Devi herself are worshipped. The Kanchikaas are served various delicacies such as puris (deep fried Indian bread), halwa (sweet dish made of suji) and Bengal gram curry. The devotees then end the fast by consuming the Prasad.

Some people end their fast on the occasion of Navami by following the same rituals. Devi Siddhidatri is worshipped on this day, who is believed to possess supernatural powers. The devotees adorn the colour purple on the occasion of Navami, the same colour donned by the deity.

The Kanchika Pujan marks the end of nine day long ceremonies and on the tenth day the Dussehra or Vijaya Dashami is celebrated to mark the victory of good over evil. Goddess Durga is ceremoniously bid adieu with hopes that happiness and prosperity prevail everywhere with her blessings.

Comment: You should cite sources.

Answer (score 2):

Our religious books have split opinion on the timing of Navratri Parana.           In religious texts two different opinions exist on the timings of breaking Navratri fast. The first opinion advises to do Navratri Parana within Navami Tithi and the second opinion advises to do Navratri Parana on Dashami Tithi only after Navami Tithi is over.

Most of the devotees in North India, either break Navratri fast on Ashtami or Navami after doing Kanya Puja. Depending on **family traditions** followed since generations, Kanya/Kumari Puja is done either on Ashtami or Navami. For those who follow this tradition, there is no need to look for Navratri Parana Muhurat as those devotees would break the fast before noon after finishing Kanya Puja.

As **FAMILY TRADITIONS >>>**

Thou it should be noted that this tradition doesn't follow the principle of nine-nights fasting during Navratri. Because, in those families who worship Ashtami Tithi, the fasting would be observed only for seven nights and for those families who worship Navami Tithi, the fasting would be observed only for eight nights. This tradition rather makes sure that Navratri fasting is broken within Navami Tithi and avoids Navratri Parana on Dashami Tithi or on the day when Navami Tithi is conjoin.

This is menrioned in Shrimad Devi Bhagwatam, 5th Skandha, Chapter 34 - On the methods of the worship of the Devī.

> Thus completing the worship of the Devī, Homa is to be done duly with Mantrams and other necessary articles on the eighth or the ninth tithi. Lastly the Brāhmins are to be fed duly; **then the worshipper is to take his first meal after fasting (i.e., make pāraṇam) on the TENTH DAY**; then presents and various articles are to be offered to the Brāhmin, according to one’s might and with devotion.

As per Nirnaya-Sindhu,

> अथ नवरात्रपारणानिर्णयः। सा च **दशम्यां** कार्या॥

The Navratri Parana is done when Navami Tithi is over and Dashami Tithi prevails. As the book mentions, Navratri fasting has been suggested from Pratipada to Navami and to follow this guideline Navratri fasting should be observed throughout Navami Tithi.
Navratri Parana time to break fasting is based on the rules mentioned in Nirnaya-Sindhu.
If Navami Tithi is getting over before sunset then fast is broken on the same day when Navami Tithi is over and Dashami Tithi is prevailing. If Navami Tithi is getting over after sunset then Navratri Parana is postponed for the next day and Navratri fast is broken after sunrise on the next day. This tradition makes sure that Navratri fasting is observed for nine-nights unless Navami Tithi is getting over before sunset. If Navami Tithi is getting over before sunset then fasting would end on the same day and fasting would be observed for eight nights only.

**Ashwina Navratri Parana Time - after 02:20 PM on Oct 04, 2022 & between 12:00 Pm of Oct 05, 2022.**                 This is the time when Navami ends and Dashmi is present.
In few families, Navratri Parana is done after Durga Visarjan which is done while Dashami Tithi prevails. Hence, for those who follow this tradition should break Navratri fasting after Durga Visarjan. Thus they must do Navaratri Parana after Durga Visarjan on Dashmi.

To cut short,
**Follow family tradition as those are laid by gyani sadhakas of family, if you had no tradition of Navaratri/Durga puja, than stick to Nirnaya sindhu as it is Shastrokt.**

**कालिकार्पणमस्तु ।**